# Neo4j Doc manager not building relationships from array of _id field

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I am trying to use Neo4j doc manager to connect data from `mongodb` to `Neo4j`.

As per the documentation of Neo4j Docmanager, I am using a _id field to link two nodes. But when I have one node connected to two different nodes. How do I do it..?

I have tried giving this value an array of `ObjectIds`, but this fails with the exception.

```
[ERROR] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:288 - Unable to process oplog document {'ns': 'metadata.titles', 'h': 8825348528118145634, 'ts': Timestamp(1499669635, 1), 'o': {'title': 'software Engineer', 'skills_id': [{'skills_id': '595ce56c813b1e12cecd61e6'}]}, 'v': 2, 'op': 'i'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/deployment/elastic5/python3/mongo-connector/mongo_connector/util.py", line 33, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/deployment/elastic5/python3/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/neo4j_doc_manager.py", line 64, in upsert
    builder = NodesAndRelationshipsBuilder(doc, doc_type, doc_id, metadata)
  File "/opt/deployment/elastic5/python3/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/nodes_and_relationships_builder.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.build_nodes_query(doc_type, doc, doc_id)
  File "/opt/deployment/elastic5/python3/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/nodes_and_relationships_builder.py", line 27, in build_nodes_query
    self.build_node_with_reference(doc_type, key, id, document[key])
  File "/opt/deployment/elastic5/python3/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/nodes_and_relationships_builder.py", line 64, in build_node_with_reference
    self.explicit_ids.update({document_key: doc_type})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Did you get any way to do the same?